# Linkedin shows 3 shared images instead of one

Tags: javascript, html, css, linkedin-api

I have a problem with Linkedin.
In the head of my One page application I have inserted following meta:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The title" /> 
<meta property="og:url" content="content of the page" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mybesite/files/logo.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpg">
```

When I share the page with linkedin, linkedin shows 3 images instead of one.
I also read this stack overflow answer, but it does not help. 
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236660/linkedin-show-3-different-image-when-sharing)
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: `but it does not help.` Have you tried this? Because it seems that although it's ugly, it suppose to work because linkedin's server doesn't read css and if you "give" him only one image it will show only it.

Comment: I tried it, of course. But linkedin is always showing 3 images.

Comment: Maybe there is a cache on their server. Maybe [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#opengraph) will help..

Comment: I also deleted them...strange...

Comment: Have you read the section `Shared Content Caching`? it answer your question exactly. TL;TR : `will be cached for a period of approximately 7 days`

Comment: hi, yes I read it.